# InputBinding CommandParameter Binding to a collection

Tags: wpf, key-bindings, inputbinding

For KeyBinding I am setting up the CommandParameter in Xaml using Binding. In the Binding has a Converter setup.

When I bind the parameter to a property (INPC) the binding system re-evaluates using the Converter.

However, when I the parameter to observable collection, on CollectionChanged the binding system does not re-evaluate. Hence I receive the initial converted value.

Is there way I trigger CommandParameter to re-evalaute on CollectionChanged.

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding MyParameter}">
      <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+D" 
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding MyParameter, 
                                          Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
        </KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+T"
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ChangedValuesCollection, 
                                                      Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter}}">
        </KeyBinding>
      </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

*In the above code, I have setup a viewmodel (datacontext). But I intend to bind the command parameter to Grid's SelectedRows collection.*

Comment: whr do you have ChangedValuesCollection, at ViewModel?

Comment: In this example, in the view model. However my goal is to bind to grid's SelectedItems

Comment: see if the answer below helps you

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the selected items of DataGrid as your command parameter you can directly bind to it. Assuming Datagrid and Textbox are in same visual tree

```
 <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+T"
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName="myDataGrid"}">
```